# Using react hook to change the value of an input after regex clean up

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a validation that automatically removes bad characters as they are typed in.  The state is changing correctly and the removal is happening correctly.  The problem I am having is updating the actual value of the input.  I basically want to give the user a warning and then automatically remove the offending character.

I have this, which works:

```
const [domain, setDomain] = useState("http://example.com/");
const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

function handleSetUrl(e){
    const regExp = /^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+$/;
    if(e.match(regExp)){
        setUrl(e)
    }else{
        console.log("Your URL can only contain numbers, letters, dashes and underscores.");
        const modUrl = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-_]/g, '');
        setUrl(modUrl)
    }
}
```

And my input:

```
<p>{domain}{url}</p>
<Input
    label="Page URL"
    inputProps={{type: "text"}}
    defaultValue={url}
    onChange={(e) => handleSetUrl(e.target.value)}
/>
```

So when the user types in offending characters (for example `/` or a space) it removes the offending character and sets my state correctly --> `setUrl(modUrl)` and the constant `url` reflects that.  The issue I am having is trying to update the `<Input` with the updated value.   If I use `defaultValue` it doesn't update when I remove the offending character using:

```
const modUrl = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-_]/g, '');
setUrl(modUrl)
```

And if I just use `value={url}` I am unable to edit the input at all.  How do I get my input to reflect the change to `setUrl` in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the input value in real time based on the modified URL, you can use the controlled component approach. Instead of using defaultValue, you can set the value prop of the  component to the url state variable, and handle the input changes by updating the url state with the modified URL.

```
const [domain, setDomain] = useState("http://example.com/");
const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

function handleSetUrl(e){
    const regExp = /^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+$/;
    if (e.match(regExp)) {
        setUrl(e);
    } else {
        console.log("Your URL can only contain numbers, letters, dashes, and underscores.");
        const modUrl = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-_]/g, '');
        setUrl(modUrl);
    }
}

return (
    <>
        <p>{domain}{url}</p>
        <Input
            label="Page URL"
            inputProps={{ type: "text" }}
            value={url} // Use the value prop to reflect the changes in real time
            onChange={(e) => handleSetUrl(e.target.value)}
        />
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an **event listener** to your input field.
`onChange`

`<input value={url}  onChange={(e) => { handleSetUrl(e.target.value) }} name="url" />`

Instead of using `defaultValue = {}`, use `value={}`, this would ensure that there is a single source of truth, as quoted by the **official React.js Documentation**.